# The right sampling ratio for bootstrapped logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, bootstrap

I am modeling a logistic regression of a binary outcome on several continuous and dichotomous variables and covariates. The sample is large, around 600k. The outcome variable is positive around 40% of the time, while some of the covariates have less coverage (not missingness), only occurring in around 10% of samples.

Is there a "right" sampling ratio for each iteration of the bootstrap procedure? If I sample 20% of the existing data for each bootstrap I still have 120k samples and can quickly run more iterations. But I have not seen a good rule of thumb as to whether this is sufficient or if I want a much higher ratio.

Comment: "Sampling ratio" and "bootstrap" are an inherent contradiction: if your samples are not the same size as the original dataset, you're not bootstrapping.  What is it you are trying to do?

Comment: I want a good estimate of the distribution of effect sizes

Comment: @Andrew you're missing whuber's point. The wild bootstrap, which by all accounts is what you should use, samples each row with replacement with equal probability. So if the fraction of cases to controls varies in each bootstrap re-sample, this is precisely how you simulate the randomness due to repeated experimentation. The only fixed thing is the overall $N$ - 600K each time.

Comment: To make matters worse (or better), with such a large dataset, it seems unlikely to me that the bootstrap will likely cause any meaningful difference in inference compared to asymptotic (usual) model summaries.

Comment: I do get the point. I was sampling my data then bootstrapping that sample for k iterations.

What I want is more confidence in my distribution of effect sizes. I don't store these data for long, so even the 600k samples is a brief snapshot over a short period. My aim is to use some sampling technique to better approximate this distribution, and I used bootstrapping procedure for that, albeit incorrectly. Is there some other procedure you would reccomend?

Comment: Per @AdamO, why don't you just fit a logistic regression as such? It looks unlikely that any resampling technique would improve on the standard large sample properties of that.

Comment: Thanks everyone. It doesn't seem like resampling will add value to my modeling approach. This is more clear to me now